# How do these 2 random values differ?

Tags: java

Is there a difference between

```java
int number = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
```

and

```java
int number = (int)(100 + Math.random() * 900);
```

for generating a random 3-digit number?

Comment: there is huge difference, `(int) (Math.random()*1000)` generates from 0 - 999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second expression guarantees to produce a 3-digit random number but the first one does not guarantee it. The first expression can produce any integer from `0` to `999`.

You can also produce a 3-digit random integer as follows:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int number = random.nextInt(900) + 100;
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. so the first statement would be a number 0-999, but and the second statement is any number between 100-999??

Comment: Correct...this is what I've mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Math.random()** from [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/):

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. Returned values are chosen pseudorandomly with (approximately) uniform distribution from that range.

For example:

```java
// Generate random number 
 double rand = Math.random(); 

// Output is different everytime this code is executed 
System.out.println("Random Number:" + rand);

//pseudorandom output: 0.5568515217910215
```

In your case:

- int number = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);  returns anything between `0` - `999`
- int number = (int)(100 + Math.random() * 900); returns anything between `100` - `999`

More information from Java **API**

> When this method is first called, it creates a single new pseudorandom-number generator, exactly as if by the expression
>   new java.util.Random()
>   This new pseudorandom-number generator is used thereafter for all calls to this method and is used nowhere else.
>
> This method is properly **synchronized** to allow correct use by more than one thread. However, if many threads need to generate **pseudorandom numbers** at a great rate, it may reduce contention for each thread to have its own pseudorandom-number generator.

So the bottom line is:

> Math.random() returns a pseudorandom double greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

In this kind of questions you should visit Java API instead. Hope it helped!